# $n$-truncation of a Simplicial Model Category

Tags: reference-request, model-categories, infinity-categories, simplicial-categories

I'm working in the category of rational $CDGAs$ and trying to find a reference/construction of a natural $2$-categorical structure via truncation of the mapping spaces.

In my head, the key point is that $CDGA$s over $\mathbb{Q}$ form a simplicial model category, where the $n$-simplices are given by $$Map(A,B)_n = Hom_{CDGA}(A, B \otimes \mathcal{A}_{PL}(\Delta^n)).$$
My guess is that there should be an $n$-truncation, where we truncate each of the mapping spaces, that turns $CDGA$ into an $(n-1)$-category.

The kind of truncation I'm imagining is that from Lurie's [Higher Topos Theory](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf) Proposition 2.3.4.12 where $n$-truncation roughly corresponds to replacing $Map(A,B)$ with $h_n Map(A,B)$, defined by:

- the $m$-simplices are $h_n Map(A,B)(m) = [\Delta^m, Map(A,B)]_n / \sim$ where
- $[\Delta^m, Map(A,B)]_n$ is the image of the restriction map $$i^* : Fun(Sk^{n+1} \Delta^m, Map(A,B)) \to Fun(Sk^{n} \Delta^m, Map(A,B))$$ induced by the inclusion of skeleta, and
- for maps $f,g \in [\Delta^m, Map(A,B)]_n$, we say $f \sim g$ if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic relative to $sk^{n-1} \Delta^m$.

with the proposition stating that $h_n(Map(A,B))$ is indeed an $n$-category.

The points I'm confused about are:

1. I'm fairly sure this only works for Kan complexes - whereas not all mapping spaces in a simplicial model category are Kan complexes. My feeling is that this is resolved somehow using the extra condition on simplicial model categories about the pullback powering being a Kan Fibration ([Definition 2.1 - Condition 3](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+model+category))
2. How do we move from truncating individual mapping spaces $Map(A,B)$, to a $2$-categorical structure on $CDGA$? I would expect that applying $h_n(Map(A,B))$ on all mapping spaces can be done directly on $CDGA$ by applying some other $\tilde{h}_{n+1}$ on CDGA directly.

I've been able to find a lot of references about this kind of truncation for quasi-categories, but nothing about simplicial model categories specifically.

In the end, what I would hope for is that doing this kind of operation at level $1$ in the mapping space would result in $2$-category (say something called $\tilde{h}_2(CDGA)$), where the objects and morphisms are the same and the $2$-cells are homotopy classes of homotopies. I tried proving this directly, but had a lot of trouble working out how the vertical and horizontal composition can be interchanged appropriately.

I was hoping to find a reference that deals with truncation in simplicial model categories. In general, I am quite confused about the passage from simplicially enriched things to quasi-categories, especially when we have simplicial model categories - which are simplicially enriched with a number of extra conditions.

Comment: Problem 1 can probably be ignored. but it depends on what exactly you are doing. The point is that the only simplicial hom sets that are homotopically relevant are those from a cofibrant object to a fibrant object - the other ones may not have the correct homotopy type. and simplicial hom set from a cofibrant to a fibrant objects are always Kan complexes. So the type of construction you are talking about should be restricted the category of bifibrant objects.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer! I wanted a 2-categorical structure on all of CDGA for what I'm doing, but reading your point convinced me that this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The OP wrote "I was hoping to find a reference that deals with truncation in simplicial model categories." In 2022, Michael Batanin and I published a paper, [Homotopy theory of algebras of substitudes and their localisation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05432) that included this concept as Definition 9.4.1. A model category is $n$-truncated if for any objects $X,Y$, the derived mapping space $Map(X,Y)$ has homotopy groups vanishing above $n$ (as pointed out in the comments, your issue (1) can be ignored; these objects are automatically (co)fibrantly replaced when we compute $Map(X,Y)$). In Section 14, we construct such model structures as left Bousfield localizations of other combinatorial, simplicial models.

You could do the same for the category CDGA over $\mathbb{Q}$, because I proved the right-induced model structure on CDGA is combinatorial and left proper in Theorems 3.2 and 4.17 of my paper [Model Structures on Commutative Monoids in General Model Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6759) (see also Example 5.1, for the context of CDGAs). Hence, you can apply truncation to the category CDGA, as you suggested to do in your (2).